# Justification of captions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I know there are a few similar questions about this, but the option `justification=justified` is not working properly on my figures. I'm getting everything but "Figure n:" justified, so the numbering labels are off justification. The same happens with `justification=centering`.
I'm using option `\captionof{figure}`, can this be the problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage,headinclude]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=justified]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}\vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Image}
\captionof{figure}[Solar atmosphere temperature-height distribution.]{Solar atmosphere temperature-height distribution as determined by \cite{15}. Height is given in kilometers measured above zero point where $\tau=1$. Regions of line formation are also indicated. From right to left: photosphere, temperature minimum (4,000K), chromosphere, transition region (8,500K) and Lyman valley (20,000K).}
\label{fig:vernazza}
\end{center}\vspace{1cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for posting an MWE. I'm not sure how to interpret your observation that

> I'm getting everything but "Figure n:" justified, so the numbering labels are off justification.

I assume you're trying to avoid "hanging indentation" of the caption material on the lines after the first one. If this interpretation is correct, you can achieve the desired effect by specifying the option `format=plain` of the `caption` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage,headinclude]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove demo option in real document
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption} % 'format=plain' avoids hanging indentation
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Image}
\captionof{figure}[Solar atmosphere temperature-height distribution.]{Solar atmosphere temperature-height distribution as determined by \cite{15}. Height is given in kilometers measured above zero point where $\tau=1$. Regions of line formation are also indicated. From right to left: photosphere, temperature minimum (4,000K), chromosphere, transition region (8,500K) and Lyman valley (20,000K).}
\label{fig:vernazza}
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work for figures. What about for tables?

Comment: @user1271772 - Did you try `\captionof{table}[...]{...}`?

Comment: Tried: \captionsetup[table]{
  labelsep=newline,
  justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  textfont=it,
}
with \usepackage{threeparttable}

Comment: oh you're talking about in the command for making the caption. The problem is that I'm using LyX. Let me try it with ERT.

Comment: tried that now. No improvement at all. Tried \captionof{table}[Table1]{Description of the table} in an ERT box within the float:Table. It worked, in that the caption still does appear exactly where it did before, despite using ERT instead of LyX's built in caption mechanism. But it's not justified at all. It's completely centered instead of left-justified.

Comment: @user1271772 - When using the `\captionof` command, one shouldn't be using "floating" environments such as `figure` and `table`. Please read the user guide of the `caption` package for information about how to override centering if the caption can be displayed on a single row. In particular, check out the top half of page 9 of the user guide. (Type `texdoc caption` at a command prompt to display the user guide.)

Comment: I have several rows @Mico