# Table caption cannot be justified using the caption package

Tags: captions, justification

I am trying to justify the caption of a table instead of centering it.

I found many questions (including [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170803/justification-of-captions)) explaining that the `caption` package proposes the option `justification=justified`. This does not work in the code sample below.

- Note that the `labelfont=bf`, passed at the same time when calling the package, is applied properly.
- Attempts to apply `format=plain` do not work either.
- I tried to move the `center` environment after the `\caption` command and it does not solve the problem.

How to justify this caption?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=justified]{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    Some data meaningless is presented in the table below to show that the \textit{justification} of the caption is not working while the \textit{labelfont} is applied properly.
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{table}[ht]
            \caption{A caption which should be justified}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
                A & B & C \\
                \hline
                a & b & c\\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{center}
        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caption package normally justifies captions which are longer than one line and centres the ones with only a single line. If you don't like this, you can switch this check off like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    Some data meaningless is presented in the table below to show that the \textit{justification} of the caption is not working while the \textit{labelfont} is applied properly.
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{table}[ht]
            \caption{A caption which should be justified}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
                A & B & C \\
                \hline
                a & b & c\\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{center}
        
\end{document}
```